# Simple Git workflow

Tags: git

I am having trouble setting up a seemingly simple workflow with Git.

Say I have two developers, DevA and DevB.  There is a remote repository called 'origin' that both developers have access to.

DevA creates a branch from 'master'...

```
git checkout -b 'newbranch'
```

DevA makes changes to newbranch and commits

```
git add .
git commit -m 'newbranch changes'
```

DevA pushes the changes to origin

```
git push --all
```

DevB wants the branches

```
git fetch --all
```

DevB wants to work on newbranch

```
git checkout newbranch
git pull newbranch
```

DevB makes changes to newbranch and pushes changes to origin

```
git add .
git commit -m 'message'
git push --all
```

DevA needs to get changes from remote and gets...

```
git checkout newbranch
git pull --all

You asked to pull from the remote '--all', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

then...

```
git branch -r

origin/newbranch
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
```

then...

```
git pull origin/newbranch

fatal: 'origin/newbranch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Seems like the correct workflow. What errors are you getting?

Comment: I clarified the question to include some of the errors.

Comment: don't use `git pull --all`, just use `git pull`, and note that it only works from a tracking branch.  You can see tracking info with `git branch -vv`.

Comment: Ok, for some reason, the branch on DevA was not tracking the remote.  We added tracking for that and git pull worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git push --all origin` or `git pull --all origin`

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong here, but I think when you used `git pull --all` it thought `--all` was the name of your remote repository.

I think `DevA` just needs to do: `git pull origin newbranch`.

Another option would be to use `git fetch origin` and then `DevA` could manually do the merge using `git merge origin/newbranch`.